# Can we have 2 different Oracle Dependency from 2 different database in a single asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, notifications

I am developing a asp.net web api application where I'm trying to get oracle database change notification in c#. But when I am Initializing 1 oracle dependency, everything is working as expected but when I am trying to Initialize 2 oracle dependency from 2 different oracle database, I am getting an error "'***This operation requires the objects to use the same connection***'"

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT EMPNO FROM EMP r WHERE rownum <= 1 Order by EMPNO Desc", con1);
con1.Open();
cmd.AddRowid = true;
var dep = new OracleDependency(cmd);
dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_OnChange);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

var cmd2 = new OracleCommand("SELECT EMPNO FROM EMP2 r WHERE rownum <= 1 Order by EMPNO Desc", con2);
con2.Open();
cmd2.AddRowid = true;
var dep2 = new OracleDependency(cmd2);
dep2.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dep2_OnChange);
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Load(cmd2.ExecuteReader());
```

Comment: Why did you set up the first dependency, then later reuse the command to ExecuteReader and the load the results into a datatable? Why not use a 3rd connection and another command for that? Which line of your code actually throws an exception?

Comment: you could try looking into linked servers, then you only need one connection

Comment: is it possible the same port has been assigned for both dependencies?  also your first call should be ExecuteNonQuery, not filling a datatable - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featChange.htm#ODPNT413

Answer (score 4):

firstly this step by step guide may resolve your issue:
[Oracle Dependency Guide](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/changenotification/odpnetchg_otn.htm)

Secondly, this is also another work around you can use to do your job.
Yes there can be. Your Database layer should contain 2 classes which will connect to the respective database. Plus don't use `ExecuteReader`, instead use `DataAdapter` because it  handles Connection.Open(), Close(), Dispose() itself.

for example

**DATABASE1.CS**

```
public class Database1
{
    string sCon = string.Empty;
    OracleConnection OraCon;
    protected string query = string.Empty;
    public Database1()
    {
       sCon = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = 1.1.1.1)(PORT = 12345)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID = SIDNAME)));User ID=username;Password=pass;";
       OraCon = new OracleConnection(sCon);
    }

    protected DataTable FillDataTableByParam(OracleParameter[] param)
    {
        DataTable oDT = new DataTable();
        OracleCommand OraCom = new OracleCommand(query, OraCon);
        OraCom.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        new OracleDataAdapter(OraCom).Fill(oDT);
        query = "";
        return oDT;
    }
}
```

**DATABASE2.CS**

```
public class Database2
{
    string sCon = string.Empty;
    OracleConnection OraCon;
    protected string query = string.Empty;
    public Database2()
    {
       sCon = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = 1.1.1.1)(PORT = 12345)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID = SIDNAME2)));User ID=username;Password=pass;";
       OraCon = new OracleConnection(sCon);
    }

    protected DataTable FillDataTableByParam(OracleParameter[] param)
    {
        DataTable oDT = new DataTable();
        OracleCommand OraCom = new OracleCommand(query, OraCon);
        OraCom.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        new OracleDataAdapter(OraCom).Fill(oDT);
        query = "";
        return oDT;
    }
}
```

But you can also keep 1 class in your Database Layer making it accessible for 2 databases, it would look something like this:

```
public class DatabaseLayer
    {
        string sCon = string.Empty;
        OracleConnection OraCon;
        protected string query = string.Empty;
        public DatabaseLayer(string DataBaseSecureName)
        {
           if(DataBaseSecureName ==  "One")
           {
            sCon = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = 1.1.1.1)(PORT = 12345)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID = SIDNAME)));User ID=username;Password=pass;";
           }
           else if (DataBaseSecureName ==  "Second")
           {
            sCon = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = 1.1.1.1)(PORT = 12345)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID = SIDNAME2)));User ID=username;Password=pass;";
           }

           OraCon = new OracleConnection(sCon);
        }

        protected DataTable FillDataTableByParam(OracleParameter[] param)
        {
            DataTable oDT = new DataTable();
            OracleCommand OraCom = new OracleCommand(query, OraCon);
            OraCom.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            new OracleDataAdapter(OraCom).Fill(oDT);
            query = "";
            return oDT;
        }
    }
```

You can add a method to the Classes/Class i wrote above with logic to return notification on change of connection, and then use it as it pleases you.

Comment: My question was not about fetching data from 2 different oracle database but start two OracleDependency from 2 different oracle database.

Comment: You are using `OracleDependency` instead you can try this approach i answered or the approach "WhatsThePoint" has shared in your question's comment section.

Comment: @ARr0w : I actually also do not understand how your approach will fulfill the need to have change notifications from the DB, without using `OracleDependency`. On the @WhatsThePoint comment, it does provide a workaround, but does not explain the cause why there's an issue when using two completely separate sets of connections, commands, dependencies and data tables.

Comment: @Hilarion Since he is having trouble using predefined libraries i have given him an easy approach to create his own to access two databases from OOP point of view.  The library he is using must be doing the same thing but differently and with some additional events attached with it.

Comment: The question is specifically for Oracle Dependency, not just a way to access two Oracle DBs.

Comment: The library he's probably using is "Oracle Data Provider for .Net", where I have not found a way to do that same thing (receive change notifications) differently.