# Display .sql output from OracleConnection C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, executescalar

There's simple .sql file like this:-

**helloworld.sql**

```
DECLARE 
   message  varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!'; 
BEGIN 
   dbms_output.put_line(message); 
END;
```

I want to call the file in C# console app, catch and display the output in console. Supposedly, it should just output `Hello, world!` in the console. This is what I've tried so far.

**Program.cs**

```
string sqlConnectionString = @"User Id=user;Password=password123;Data Source=xxxx.xxx.COM";
string script = File.ReadAllText(@"\\test\\helloworld.sql");
try
{
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = sqlConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        var cmd = new OracleCommand(script, con);
        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.Write(result.ToString());
    }
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SQL Exception: " + e.Message);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
}
```

But I got an `Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Then I'm aware about [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/812069/What-is-the-difference-between-ExecuteScalar-Execu), so I tried using `ExecuteNonQuery()` but because there's actually nothing I retrieve from database, the output is `-1`.

I just want to know how can I capture the output `Hello, world!` from the .sql file and print it in the C# console?

**UPDATE:**

After go through the comments, I got the idea to try search about `DBMS_OUTPUT`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53587008/8418093) help me to print the output successfully. Thanks.

Comment: which line did you get the exception?

Comment: this might answer your question : [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884783/can-we-have-2-different-oracle-dependency-from-2-different-database-in-a-single/50965911#50965911)

Comment: @er-sho right after this line: `Console.Write(result.ToString());` it goes directly to catch execption block.

Comment: ***If*** whatever's written by `dbms_output.put_line` is going to be made available to you, I believe it'll be sent to the handler you attach to the connection's `InfoMessage` event.

Comment: The `result` may return `null` if no data is present in result set when `ExecuteScalar` executed. Also as far as I know, you can retrieve the messages with `DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE`, but make sure that it runs on the same Oracle session.

Comment: @madreflection do you have any link related to this?

Comment: No, it's an assumption based on how `SqlConnection` works.

Comment: I found a reference about how to use `dbms_output.get_line` in ODP.NET, you can check it [here](https://oradim.blogspot.com/2007/05/odpnet-tip-retrieving-dbmsoutput-text.html). You need to provide `OracleParameter` with output direction to get output text from PL/SQL command.

Comment: I confirmed that SQL Server's PRINT statements are sent to `SqlConnection`'s `InfoMessage` event handler. I believe it's reasonable that ODP.NET might do the same with `dbms_output.put_line`. Try this: at the start of your using block, `var outputLines = new List<string>(); con.InfoMessage += (s, e) => outputLines.Add(e.Message);` and then use `ExecuteNonQuery` to run your original script.

Comment: The documentation for [InfoMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/ConnectionInfoMessage.htm) says *"This event is triggered for any message or warning sent by the database."* so that test should confirm if that includes what's written using `dbms_output.put_line`.

Comment: @madreflection i'm using OracleConnection instead of SqlConnection can it still be done?

Comment: I understand that, which is why I said "it's reasonable that ODP.NET might do the same," in order to recognize that you're using something different. You should try what I suggested. I don't have an Oracle installation available, or else I would have tried it and made it an answer if it worked. You have enough information to run the test yourself.

Comment: @madreflection i've tried it inside the using block. it does not show the output.

Comment: Did you look at what's in `outputLines` after it ran?  All that code is supposed to do is accumulate the lines. After `ExecuteNonQuery`, you can iterate through `outputLines` and do anything you want with them, such as writing them to the console.

Comment: @madreflection yes, after `ExecuteNonQuery()`, the outputlines does not contains anything.